# I want to understand the checkbox states

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

There are 3 product cards on my page; they initially come with an external API. These cards contain checkboxes and a color selection palette. The user can change the linked and active states, as well as select the colors of the palette of these cards. By clicking on the icon (i), a pop-up is displayed asking you to go to the profile page. And on this page, in the end, there should be all the cards that have the property of being linked with all other conditions taken into account

if one product card receives an active badge, then this badge is removed from other cards

[image: WidgetsPage]

profile page is almost identical

```
const ProductWidgetsPage: React.FC = () => {
    const [productWidgets, setProductWidgets] = useState<IProductWidget[]>([]);
    const [linkedProductCards, setLinkedProductCards] = useState<IProductWidget[]>([]);
    const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [selectedWidget, setSelectedWidget] = useState<IProductWidget | null>(null);
    const [hoveredElement, setHoveredElement] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const widgets: IProductWidget[] = await fetchProductWidgets();
                setProductWidgets(widgets);
                setLinkedProductCards(widgets.map(widget => ({ ...widget, selectedColor: widget.selectedColor || '' })));
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching product widgets:', error);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const handleToggleActive = (widget: IProductWidget) => {
        setProductWidgets(prevProductWidgets => {
            const updatedProductWidgets = prevProductWidgets.map(prevWidget => ({
                ...prevWidget,
                active: prevWidget.id === widget.id,
            }));
            return updatedProductWidgets;
        });
    };

    const handleLinkedChange = (updatedWidget: IProductWidget) => {
        setLinkedProductCards(prevLinkedProductCards => {
            const updatedIndex = prevLinkedProductCards.findIndex(widget => widget.id === updatedWidget.id);
            if (updatedWidget.linked) {
                if (updatedIndex !== -1) {
                    console.log('Updated existing widget:', updatedWidget);
                    const updatedLinkedProductCards = [...prevLinkedProductCards];
                    updatedLinkedProductCards[updatedIndex] = updatedWidget;
                    return updatedLinkedProductCards;
                } else {
                    console.log('Adding new widget:', updatedWidget);
                    const newLinkedProductCards = [...prevLinkedProductCards, updatedWidget];
                    return newLinkedProductCards;
                }
            } else {
                return prevLinkedProductCards.filter(card => card.linked);
            }
        });
    };

    const handleColorChange = (widgetId: string, newColor: any) => {
        setProductWidgets(prevProductWidgets =>
            prevProductWidgets.map(prevWidget =>
                prevWidget.id.toString() === widgetId.toString() ? { ...prevWidget, selectedColor: newColor } : prevWidget
            )
        );
    };

    const handleTooltipEnter = (widget: IProductWidget, event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        setSelectedWidget(widget);
        setModalOpen(true);
        setHoveredElement(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const closeModal = () => {
        setModalOpen(false);
    };

    const handleViewProfile = () => {
        navigate('/profile', { state: { allProductCards: linkedProductCardsFiltered } });
    };

    const linkedProductCardsFiltered = useMemo(
        () => linkedProductCards.filter(card => card.linked),
        [linkedProductCards]
    );

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <WrapperComponent title='Per product widgets'>
                {productWidgets.map(widget => (
                    <ProductCard
                        key={widget.id}
                        {...widget}
                        onToggleActive={() => handleToggleActive(widget)}
                        onTooltipEnter={e => handleTooltipEnter(widget, e)}
                        onLinkedChange={handleLinkedChange}
                        onColorChange={newColor => handleColorChange(widget.id.toString(), newColor)}
                    />
                ))}
            </WrapperComponent>

            {selectedWidget && hoveredElement && (
                <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} onClose={closeModal} triggerElement={hoveredElement}>
                    <p className="modal-tooltip-text">
                        This widget links directly to your public profile so that you can easily share your impact with your customers.
                        Turn it off here if you do not want the badge to link to it.
                    </p>
                    <button className="modal-tooltip-button" onClick={handleViewProfile}>
                        View Public Profile
                    </button>
                </Modal>
            )}
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

I have already rebuilt all the state handlers several times. **It seems to me that the data is overwriting each other somewhere.** Because the change in the active state does not occur correctly and is not reflected in the final array, which should go to the profile

```
interface IProductCard extends IProductWidget {
    onToggleActive: () => void;
    onTooltipEnter: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
    onLinkedChange: (updatedWidget: IProductWidget) => void;
    onColorChange: (newColor: string) => void;
}

const ProductCard: FC<IProductCard> = ({
    id,
    type,
    amount,
    action,
    active,
    linked,
    selectedColor,
    onToggleActive,
    onTooltipEnter,
    onLinkedChange,
    onColorChange,
}) => {
    const [isLinked, setIsLinked] = useState(linked);
    const [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState(selectedColor);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLinked(linked);
    }, [linked]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentColor(selectedColor);
    }, [selectedColor]);

    const handleColorSelect = (color: any) => {
        setCurrentColor(color);
        onColorChange(color);
    };

    const handleisLinkedChange = () => {
        const updatedWidget = { id, type, amount, action, active, linked: !isLinked, selectedColor };
        setIsLinked(!isLinked);
        onLinkedChange(updatedWidget);
    };

    const handleTooltipOpen = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        onTooltipEnter(event);
    };

    const handleisActiveChange = () => {
        onToggleActive();
    };
    
    const getLogoByColor = () => {
        return PaletteColorsList[currentColor] === PaletteColorsList.beige || PaletteColorsList[currentColor] === PaletteColorsList.white
            ? logo_green
            : logo;
    };

    const textColor = PaletteColorsList[currentColor] === PaletteColorsList.beige || PaletteColorsList[currentColor] === PaletteColorsList.white
        ? 'product-card-text-green'
        : 'product-card-text';

    return (
        <div className="product-card">
            <div className="product-card-top" style={{ backgroundColor: PaletteColorsList[selectedColor] }}>
                <img src={getLogoByColor()} alt="greenspark logo" className="product-card-logo" />
                <div className={textColor}>
                    <p className="product-card-text-action">This product {action}</p>
                    <p className="product-card-text-amount">
                        {amount} {type}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="product-card-container">
                <label className="product-card-label-text" htmlFor={`linkedTo-${id}`}>
                    Link to Public Profile
                    <img
                        src={tooltip}
                        id={`tooltip-${id}`}
                        alt="tooltip"
                        onMouseEnter={handleTooltipOpen}
                    />
                </label>
                <div className="checkbox-wrapper">
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        id={`linkedTo-${id}`}
                        className="product-card-checkbox"
                        checked={isLinked}
                        onChange={handleisLinkedChange}
                    />
                    <span className="checkbox"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <PaletteSelector onSelectColor={handleColorSelect} currentColor={currentColor}/>

            <div className="product-card-container">
                <label className="product-card-label-text" htmlFor={`activateBadge-${id}`}>
                    Activate badge
                </label>
                <div className="toggle-wrapper">
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        id={`activateBadge-${id}`}
                        checked={active}
                        onChange={handleisActiveChange}
                        className="product-card-toggle"
                    />
                    <span className="toggle"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

[this is API link](https://api.mocki.io/v2/016d11e8/product-widgets)
I will also show the product card so you can see the event handlers inside

Comment: Those `useEffects` are not necessary.  Delete them then see where you are.

Comment: Yes, I deleted it from ProductCard, it got much better
But the initial state still overlaps somewhere. For some reason, the first element always gets into the filtered array, even if the linked checkbox is cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a fair amount of "code smells" here but let's just focus on the actual problem first.

`handleViewProfile` pushes `linkedProductCardsFiltered` over the push state to the profile page. This is extrapolated from `linkedProductCards`.

However, the active state handler `handleToggleActive` mutates `productWidgets`. But this is a different state item to `linkedProductCards`. Effectively, it is a copy.

You generally never want to keep around more than one canonical source of some state. This probably isn't related but this same code smell also exists in the `ProductCard` component where you are copying the linked/colour state into the local component state. This creates a pointless clone and increases the surface area for bugs as well as creates more work for yourself to keep multiple copies of the state in sync that should not exist in the first place. I suspect a lot of this is to workaround toggling not working properly, but that's just a symptom of the root cause of not having one canonical place to keep everything.

The checkbox `onChange` was wired in wrong also as you need to reference `event.target.checked` rather than relying on toggling an unnecessary state item, which would be error-prone.

Generally speaking, an instant red flag for this is an effect which puts props into the state.

Let's rethink. `linkedProductCards` probably does not need to exist. If we want to only send the linked ones over the push state, we can just derive that already from one canonical source if we rewire everything to `productWidgets` by simply filtering that. No need to keep two pieces of state around that semi-mirror each other.

It's also best to pass around IDs that reference the widget and not the whole thing here to avoid any chance of stale references.

**ProductWidgetsPage**

```
const ProductWidgetsPage: React.FC = () => {
    const [productWidgets, setProductWidgets] = useState<IProductWidget[]>([]);
    const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [selectedWidget, setSelectedWidget] = useState<IProductWidget | null>(null);
    const [hoveredElement, setHoveredElement] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const widgets: IProductWidget[] = await fetchProductWidgets();
                setProductWidgets(widgets);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching product widgets:', error);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);


    const handleToggleActive= (id: string, active: boolean) => {
        setProductWidgets(prevProductWidgets => {
            const updatedProductWidgets = prevProductWidgets.map(prevWidget => ({
                ...prevWidget,
                active: prevWidget.id === id ? active : false,
            }));
            return updatedProductWidgets;
        });
    };

    const handleToggleLinked = (id: string, linked: boolean) => {
       setProductWidgets(prevProductWidgets =>
            prevProductWidgets.map(prevWidget =>
                prevWidget.id === id ? { ...prevWidget, linked } : prevWidget
            )
        );
    };

    const handleColorChange = (id: string, newColor: any) => {
        setProductWidgets(prevProductWidgets =>
            prevProductWidgets.map(prevWidget =>
                prevWidget.id === id ? { ...prevWidget, selectedColor: newColor } : prevWidget
            )
        );
    };

    const handleTooltipEnter = (widget: IProductWidget, event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        setSelectedWidget(widget);
        setModalOpen(true);
        setHoveredElement(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const closeModal = () => {
        setModalOpen(false);
    };

    const handleViewProfile = () => {
        navigate('/profile', { state: { allProductCards: productWidgets.filter(card => card.linked) } });
    };


    return (
        <Fragment>
            <WrapperComponent title='Per product widgets'>
                {productWidgets.map(widget => (
                    <ProductCard
                        key={widget.id}
                        {...widget}
                        onToggleActive={(active) => handleToggleActive(widget.id, active)}
                        onTooltipEnter={e => handleTooltipEnter(widget, e)}
                        onLinkedChange={linked => handleToggleLinked(widget.id, linked)}
                        onColorChange={newColor => handleColorChange(widget.id, newColor)}
                    />
                ))}
            </WrapperComponent>

            {selectedWidget && hoveredElement && (
                <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} onClose={closeModal} triggerElement={hoveredElement}>
                    <p className="modal-tooltip-text">
                        This widget links directly to your public profile so that you can easily share your impact with your customers.
                        Turn it off here if you do not want the badge to link to it.
                    </p>
                    <button className="modal-tooltip-button" onClick={handleViewProfile}>
                        View Public Profile
                    </button>
                </Modal>
            )}
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

**ProductCard**

```
interface IProductCard extends IProductWidget {
    onToggleActive: (active: boolean) => void;
    onTooltipEnter: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
    onLinkedChange: (linked: boolean) => void;
    onColorChange: (newColor: string) => void;
}

const ProductCard: FC<IProductCard> = ({
    id,
    type,
    amount,
    action,
    active,
    linked,
    selectedColor,
    onToggleActive,
    onTooltipEnter,
    onLinkedChange,
    onColorChange,
}) => {


    const handleTooltipOpen = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        onTooltipEnter(event);
    };

    const getLogoByColor = () => {
        return PaletteColorsList[selectedColor] === PaletteColorsList.beige || PaletteColorsList[selectedColor] === PaletteColorsList.white
            ? logo_green
            : logo;
    };

    const textColor = PaletteColorsList[selectedColor] === PaletteColorsList.beige || PaletteColorsList[selectedColor] === PaletteColorsList.white
        ? 'product-card-text-green'
        : 'product-card-text';

    return (
        <div className="product-card">
            <div className="product-card-top" style={{ backgroundColor: PaletteColorsList[selectedColor] }}>
                <img src={getLogoByColor()} alt="greenspark logo" className="product-card-logo" />
                <div className={textColor}>
                    <p className="product-card-text-action">This product {action}</p>
                    <p className="product-card-text-amount">
                        {amount} {type}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="product-card-container">
                <label className="product-card-label-text" htmlFor={`linkedTo-${id}`}>
                    Link to Public Profile
                    <img
                        src={tooltip}
                        id={`tooltip-${id}`}
                        alt="tooltip"
                        onMouseEnter={handleTooltipOpen}
                    />
                </label>
                <div className="checkbox-wrapper">
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        id={`linkedTo-${id}`}
                        className="product-card-checkbox"
                        checked={linked}
                        onChange={(event) => onLinkedChange(event.target.checked)}
                    />
                    <span className="checkbox"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <PaletteSelector onSelectColor={onColorChange} currentColor={selectedColor}/>

            <div className="product-card-container">
                <label className="product-card-label-text" htmlFor={`activateBadge-${id}`}>
                    Activate badge
                </label>
                <div className="toggle-wrapper">
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        id={`activateBadge-${id}`}
                        checked={active}
                        onChange={(event) => onToggleActive(event.target.checked)}
                        className="product-card-toggle"
                    />
                    <span className="toggle"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
You analyzed everything so thoroughly and efficiently that I read it and was impressed by the simplicity and elegance of the solution

Separately, thank you very much for sorting out my mistakes, I’m self-taught, and I often don’t have enough such feedback to understand